# Action menu item not showing on first page of viewpager for pre Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have built an app which works perfectly on Android 4.2-4.4 but now I need to provide support for users on 4.1 and possibly 4.0 also. I have set the minSDKVersion to 15 in the Android manifest file. I have a viewpager which has an action menu for each fragment. One of the buttons (the single tick) on this action menu can show and hide per each page in the viewpager depending on some boolean variable that is worked out in the onActivityCreated method. The problem I have is that whenever I open the viewpager the first page does not have this menu item showing. If I swipe to the next page and back again then it shows up. This does not happen in Android 4.2 or above and so I thought it may be an issue with using nested fragments but I don't see why its a problem solely on the first page.

The structure of my app: Main Activity -> ListFragment -> ListFragment -> ViewPager

Image of the icons: i.stack.imgur.com/LtuFG.png

Some of the code:

ViewPager:

```
package com.dremq.dremq.activities;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.dremq.dremq.R;
import com.dremq.dremq.model.*;
import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;
import com.dremq.dremq.model.CustomMethods;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.marking_options_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // option to mark the entire quiz
            case R.id.markAll:
                // make modifications to database

                // notify the adapter that data has changed to force a UI update.
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // invalidate the options menu to force a reload of the menu.
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;

            // option to reset the entire quiz
            case R.id.reset:
                // set reset to true to enforce the correct function in getItemPosition
                reset = true;

                // make modifications to database

                // notify the adapter that data has changed to force a UI update.
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // set reset to false to stop getItemPosition from running the incorrect function
                reset = false;

                // invalidate the options menu to force a reload of the menu.
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseManager.createDatabase(getActivity());

        // Get the data past from the previous fragment.
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // If there is data in the bundle then extract the Quiz ID and load the correct Question and Attempt data
        if (bundle != null){
            quizID = bundle.getInt("QUIZ_ID");

            // if this quiz not been attempted before then add it as a new attempt in the database.
            if (!Query_Attempt.attemptedBefore(quizID)){
                Query_Attempt.addAttempt(quizID);
                attemptID = Query_Attempt.getLastAttemptID(quizID);
                Query_AttemptQuestion.addMultipleAttemptQuestion(attemptID, questionList);
            }


            // get the id for the last attempt at this quiz
            attemptID = Query_Attempt.getLastAttemptID(quizID);

            markedAll = Query_Attempt.isComplete(attemptID);
        }

        // get the viewpager container from the UI.
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Getting the adaptor by passing the fragment manager.
        adapter = new SlidingPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




    public class SlidingPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public SlidingPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new QuestionItemFragment();

            // Create a new Bundle object to transfer any required data e.g, the id of the clicked item.
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("QUESTION_ID", questionList.get(position).getQuestionID());
            bundle.putInt("ATTEMPT_ID", attemptID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return questionList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object){

            // get the fragment for the specific viewpager item from the object.
            QuestionItemFragment f = (QuestionItemFragment) object;
            if (f != null) {
                if (reset){
                    f.reset(attemptID);
                }else{
                    f.update();
                }
            }
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewPagerItem:

```
package com.dremq.dremq.activities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.dremq.dremq.R;
import com.dremq.dremq.animation.ExpandAnimation;
import com.dremq.dremq.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ViewPagerItem extends Fragment implements Updateable, Resetable{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.marking_single_options_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseManager.createDatabase(getActivity());

        // Get the data past from the previous fragment.
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // If there is data in the bundle then extract the question and attempt ID and load the correct question data
        if (bundle != null){

            // check if the question is complete
            complete = Query_AttemptQuestion.isComplete(attemptQuestionID);

            if (complete){
                correctOptionIDs = Query_Question_Option.getCorrectIDsList(questionID);
                markedAll = Query_Attempt.isComplete(attemptID);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }

        list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting the adaptor by passing the ArrayList containing the data.
        adaptor = new OptionMenuAdaptor(getActivity(), question_info.getOptions());
        list.setAdapter(adaptor);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // option to mark a single question.
            case R.id.markSingle:
                Log.i("markSingle", "Mark single question");

                // set complete to true so that UI can be corrected.
                complete = true;

                // notify the adapter that data has changed to force a UI update.
                adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // invalidate the options menu to force a reload of the menu.
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        // complete shows that the question is marked so hide the mark single question option
        if (complete){
            menu.findItem(R.id.markSingle).setVisible(false);
        }
        // marked all shows that the entire quiz is marked so hide the option to mark quiz and show reset button
        if (markedAll){
            menu.findItem(R.id.markAll).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.reset).setVisible(true);
        }
    }


    private class OptionMenuAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Option> data;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        private int height;
        private ArrayList<Boolean> expanded;


        public OptionMenuAdaptor(Activity activity, ArrayList<Option> data) {
            this.data = data;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_list_item, null);
            }

            // get the view for the option text
            final CheckedTextView optionText = (CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.option_text);

            final ListView listView = ((ListView) parent);

            // Retrieve the data from the ArrayList used to populate the particular data item.
            final Option option_info = data.get(position);

            // set the correct text for this individual item.
            optionText.setText(option_info.getOptionText());

            if (complete){
                // set up the views for a marked question
            }else{
                // set up the views for a unmarked question
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

ListFragment:

```
package com.dremq.dremq.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.dremq.dremq.R;
import com.dremq.dremq.model.*;
import de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuizMenuFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseManager.createDatabase(getActivity());

        // Get the data past from the previous fragment.
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // If there is data in the bundle then extract the category ID and load the correct Quiz data
        if (bundle != null){
            categoryID = bundle.getInt("CATEGORY_ID");
            quizList = Query_Quiz.getQuizzes(categoryID);
        }

        // find the list layout view in the current layout.
        list = (EnhancedListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting the adaptor by passing the ArrayList containing the data.
        adaptor = new QuizMenuAdaptor(getActivity(), quizList);
        list.setAdapter(adaptor);

        String[] category = Query_Category.getCategory("User");

        // Implements the click event for a single menu item. This creates a new Question Option fragment and passes it the Quiz ID.
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new QuestionOptionFragment();

                // Create a new Bundle object to transfer any required data e.g, the id of the clicked item.
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("QUIZ_ID", quizList.get(position).getQuizID());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                // Begin the transaction to change fragments.
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Set which layout container is having the view changed.
                fragmentTransaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), fragment); // can be used to load the correct layout when using this class as a generic class e.g. in exam builder and in categories list.

                // add the item to the back stack allowing the user to return to this view by clicking the back button
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // set the transition animation
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

                // commit the transition and show the changes to the user.
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

What I have tried already:

- Changing from using support-v13.jar to support-v4.jar
- Adding the menu loaded in each page to the menu loaded in the viewpager. This is what I originally had but unfortunately this creates a similar issue whereby there is a blank area showing as the furthest most right item when the item should be hidden, again only on the first page and can be 'fixed' by swiping to the next page and back again.
- Moving the menus to the MainActivity - similar issue whereby now the double tick icon does not show on the first page but shows when you swipe to the next page and back.
- Loading the viewpager directly as the first fragment (i.e. bypassing the two listviews) - this works!
- Loading one ListFragment and then the ViewPager - same issues occur

To summarise - The actionbar item is not showing on the first page of the viewpager but will show once you swipe to the next page and back. This only occurs on Android versions older than 4.2.